# Error in .vdisplay.start() - xvfbwrapper is not working

Tags: python, selenium, xvfb

installed xvfbwrapper python module.provided  display start in python selenium test in MAC

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

class San(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        #display = Display(visible=0, size=(1480, 2000))
        #display.start()
        self.vdisplay = Xvfb(width=1480, height=2000)
        self.vdisplay.start()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

While running the test case , error occur

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "san98.py", line 34, in setUp
    self.vdisplay.start()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xvfbwrapper.py", line 53, in start
    stderr=open(os.devnull),
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How to fix this issue

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```